# Sharing static content and mvc controllers on same path

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, static-content

Apologies if this feels repetitive, I gather alot of people ask about this but I haven't been able to find an answer that works.

I have a web-app, built using maven. I use Spring 4 MVC to deliver a RESTful Json API. I also have a lot of static content (html, css, js) were I use Angular.js to put a pretty face on the data API.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get both of these being served at the same time without messing with their paths.

- I'd really like to go to `{APP_ROOT}/people/{id}` in my browser, and be interacting directly with my REST api without any crap about `/api/` or `/rest/`
- I'd really like to go to `{APP_ROOT}/css/style.css` in my browser, and be served content from `src/main/webapp/css/style.css` without any crap about `resources` or `static`
- **Additionally**, I'd really like to configure all of this with annotated Java classes, and not have any `web.xml`, `application-context.xml`, etc.

So, the Spring dispatcher servlet should be handling all of the REST resource paths, and then falling back to the default Tomcat/Jetty handler for the static content.  I thought this was exactly the scenario **default-servlet-handler** was intended for? I can't seem to get it to work.

These are my relevant configuration classes:

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0] ;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/*" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
    }

}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.example.package"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

With this configuration I can interact with the REST api, but not the static content. The default servlet handler seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

To access static resource like css js or html keep all these files inside webapp folder of your module. Suppose all you static resources are in src/main/webapp/static path you can do mvc resource mapping like below in context xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/index-dev.html" location="/static/index-dev.html"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/index.html" location="/static/index.html"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/app.js" location="/static/app.js"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/appinit.js" location="/static/appinit.js"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/extjs/**" location="/static/extjs/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/static/app/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/static/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
```

Now since you want to do it without xml you can do it in your WebConfig  class like below example

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("/static/index.html");
```

}

Comment: This still doesn't seem ideal, as I have to manually list each file. Or I need to put things off in some 'static' branch, which is one of the major things I was trying to avoid. Surely there is some way to elegantly fall back to tomcat/jetty serving static content when there isn't a valid spring controller? Isn't that what default-sevlet-handler is supposed to do?

Comment: Also, with this approach, how would I get `index.html` to be accessible directly from `{APP_ROOT}` in the browser?

Comment: Since in your servlet you are using "/*"  mapping which means every request even a static content request have to go through a spring servlet. That's why you'll need mvc:resources mapping. If you don't want your static content request to go through spring servlet remove "/*" and instead give some specific mapping like for rest api which start from api keyword you can give mapping "api/*"